# Hibernate Table is not getting created with @onetomany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created three entity classes whose relation is defined as follows:
Screen -----> has many ConfigurableRows 
ConfigurableRows -----> Has many Seats.

When i am trying to persist the Screen Class object no table is getting creating.

I am attaching my entity classes here.

```
public class Screen {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int screenid;

private String screenName;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=ConfigurableRow.class, mappedBy="screenid", fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ConfigurableRow> rows;

public Screen(){
    rows = new ArrayList<ConfigurableRow>(10);
}

public Screen(int rowSize){
    rows = new ArrayList<ConfigurableRow>(rowSize);
}

public String getScreenName() {
    return screenName;
}

public void setScreenName(String screenName) {
    this.screenName = screenName;
}

public int getScreenid() {
    return screenid;
}

public void setScreenid(int screenid) {
    this.screenid = screenid;
}

public List<ConfigurableRow> getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(List<ConfigurableRow> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}
```

}

```
public class ConfigurableRow implements List<Seat>, IConfigureRow , IRow  {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int rowId;
private int numberOfSeats;
private String rowName;
private String screenName;

private int screenid;

@ElementCollection
List<Seat> seats;

public ConfigurableRow(){
    this.numberOfSeats = 10;
    this.rowName = "Default";
    this.screenName = "Default";
    this.seats = new ArrayList<>(numberOfSeats);
}

public ConfigurableRow(int numberOfSeats,String screenName , String rowName){
    this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
    this.rowName = rowName;
    this.screenName = screenName;
    this.seats = new ArrayList<Seat>(numberOfSeats);
}



public int getRowId() {
    return rowId;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Screen.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn (name="screenid",referencedColumnName="screenid",nullable=false,unique=false)
public int getScreenid() {
    return screenid;
}

public void setScreenid(int screenid) {
    this.screenid = screenid;
}

public List<Seat> getSeats() {
    return seats;
}

public void setSeats(List<Seat> seats) {
    this.seats = seats;
}

public String getRowName() {
    return rowName;
}

public String getScreenName() {
    return screenName;
}

@Override
public boolean add(Seat e) {
    return seats.add(e);
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Seat> c) {
    if(c.size() >= numberOfSeats){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seat Limit Exceeds!!!!!");
    }
    else {
        return addAll(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    seats.clear();
}

@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return seats.contains(o);
}

@Override
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return seats.containsAll(c);
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return seats.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public Iterator<Seat> iterator() {
    return seats.iterator();
}

@Override
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    return seats.remove(o);
}

@Override
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return seats.removeAll(c);
}

@Override
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return seats.removeAll(c);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return seats.size();
}

@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    return seats.toArray();
}

@Override
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    return seats.toArray(a);
}

@Override
public boolean addSeat(Seat seat) {
    if(seats.size() >= numberOfSeats){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seat Limit Exceeds!!!!!");
    } else{
        return add(seat);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean addSeat(Seat seat, int seatNumber) {
    if(seats.size() >= numberOfSeats){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seat Limit Exceeds!!!!!");
    } else{
        add(seatNumber,seat);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Seat> c) {
    if(seats.size() + c.size() > numberOfSeats){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else {
        return seats.addAll(index, c);
    }
}

@Override
public Seat get(int index) {
    return seats.get(index);
}

@Override
public Seat set(int index, Seat element) {
    return seats.set(index, element);
}

@Override
public void add(int index, Seat element) {
    seats.add(index, element);
}

@Override
public Seat remove(int index) {
    return seats.remove(index);
}

@Override
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    return seats.indexOf(o);
}

@Override
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
    return seats.lastIndexOf(o);
}

@Override
public ListIterator<Seat> listIterator() {
    return seats.listIterator();
}

@Override
public ListIterator<Seat> listIterator(int index) {
    return seats.listIterator(index);
}

@Override
public List<Seat> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    return seats.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
}


public int getNumberOfSeats() {
    return numberOfSeats;
}

public void setNumberOfSeats(int numberOfSeats) {
    this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
}

public List<Seat> getRowSet() {
    return seats;
}

public void setRowSet(List<Seat> rowSet) {
    this.seats = rowSet;
}
```

}

```
public class Seat implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8083252956190536785L;

/*@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int seatid;*/

private int seatNumber;

private SeatType seatType;

public int getSeatNumber() {
    return seatNumber;
}

public void setSeatNumber(int seatNumber) {
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
}

public SeatType getSeatType() {
    return seatType;
}

public void setSeatType(SeatType seatType) {
    this.seatType = seatType;
}
```

}

I am new to hibernate. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong here.

My Tables are getting created now . But with out any values. Hence foreign key violation error is coming.

Comment: Tables are not created when you perform DML with Hibernate. What you probably want is to utilize [hbm2ddl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do).

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a OneToMany bidirectional relationship so 
in the class **ConfigurableRow** you have to add an object from **Screen** class with annotation @ManyToOne

```
@ManyToOne
private Screen screen
```

Comment: After adding the above code I am getting as exception which says :
Could not determine type for: org.cab.domain.screens.Screen, at table: ConfigurableRow, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(screen)]

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put the onetomany annotation before your getrows() method.

`@OneToMany(targetEntity=ConfigurableRow.class, mappedBy="screenid", fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
public List<ConfigurableRow> getRows() {
    return rows;
}`

Comment: This gives me below exception :
Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Screen, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(rows)]